# problems with opening vegan

Tags: r, vegan

I Installed the package "vegan" but cant seem to run it. When I use the command library(vegan) I get this message

[image: this message].

Any ideas? I normally just use R cmdr so excuse me if this is a silly question.

Also: Is there any plugin to cmdr for NMDS ordination that I can use instead?

Comment: That message shouldn't actually prevent you from using the `vegan` package. It appears to have loaded just fine. Is there something else that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

That wasn't a "problem". It was only a "message" and not even a particularly dangerous message. It was telling you that the vegan package had a function of the same name as another function in the pls package. If you know that you will be using the `scores` function with the syntax of the `pls::scores` function at a later time, then you will need to use it with that form. If you just use `scores` you will get the function as it exists in `pkg:vegan`.

I'm being mute about the second part (although it may be premised incorrectly on your anxiety about the message, in which case the question is moot). Multipart questions are discouraged on SO.

Comment: OK I see. Im very new on anything R not cmdr (and a tiny bit of studio) so you might just have to excuse me if any of this seems ridicously simple to everyone else. But after I get that message nothing opens.. Im just stuck in the R console with that message.

Comment: You aren't stuck. The R console is waiting for you to type in a command. Try typing: `help(pac=vegan)`

Comment: There is no problem with using vegan. There may be a problem, if you want to use the scores function for pls object. Or then not: the packages may work just fine together. But be beware. I don't know how these two packages work together.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about **Rcmdr**  plugin for NMDS: check **BiodiversityR** package that provides an **Rcmdr** GUI to a part of **vegan** (plus more).